# Function that is continuous but not absolutely integrable

Tags: real-analysis

What is an example of a function $f : (0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continuous on $(0, 1]$ such that $\lim_{c \rightarrow 0} \int_c^1 f(x) dx$ exists but $\lim_{c \rightarrow 0} \int_c^1 |f(x)| dx$ does not?

Comment: Do you have any idea what such a function might look like?

Comment: Check out Olmsted and Gelbaum's *Counterexamples in analysis*.

Comment: Well, I thought that something like $f(x) = \frac 1 x \sin(\frac 1 x)$ would satisfy this, but I'm not sure if it's integrable.

Comment: @onesix that function is integrable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example this question: [$\frac{|\sin x|}{x}$ is not integrable on $[1,\infty)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899579/frac-sin-xx-is-not-integrable-on-1-infty) and make the substitution $x=1/y$ on all the integrals. You obtain precisely the function in your comments.

More explicitly, let $c$ be small, and $C=1/c$. THen
$$\int_c^1\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)}{y}dy=-\int_C^1\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\int_1^C\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$
by making the substitution $x=\frac{1}{y}$, $dx=-\frac{dy}{y^2}$, . Since the right-hand side limit for $C\to\infty$, or equivalently $c\to 0^+$, exists, then the left-hand side limit exists as well. A similar change of variables proves that
$$\lim_{c\to 0^+}\int_c^1\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)}{y}dy=\infty.$$